# Solr server installation issue

Tags: linux, curl, solr, proxy

I have installed solr server on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.I am able to access`http://solrserver:8983/solr` but when i do  `curl http://solrserver:8983/solr`
Its giving me “Proxy authorization error”
What can be the problem? Is it due to corporate firewalls?
I have given proxy settings in .bashrc file ,/etc/apt/apt.conf  and in /etc/environment file and restarted the machine
But did not work.

Thanks And Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/10572.htm and try using 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '202.95.141.129:8080');

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker